# cannot import sklearn even though it is installed successfully

Tags: python

I have installed sklearn through pip successfully using this command:

```
$pip install -U scikit-learn
```

But I cannot import it.

```
import sklearn
```

Result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it on the correct of python that you're running the script on as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try installing [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/): `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: I did `pip install --force-reinstall scikit-learn` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try pip3 install sklearn.
This will install the libraries you need for python 3.